# Merge two similar dataframes that have the same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'd like to merge df_1 and df_2 to create df_merged, but I want to merge columns that both have in common, rather than have the likes of A_x and A_y created.

```
index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
         np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two',])]
columns = ["A",  "B"]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=index, columns=columns)

index = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz',]),
         np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two',])]
columns = ["A",  "B"]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=index, columns=columns)

df_merge = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

print df_1
print df_2
print df_merge
```

**df_1**

```
                A         B
foo one  2.082229  1.575985
    two -0.805592  0.444195
qux one  0.368874  0.253556
    two  1.017632 -0.471978
```

**df_2**

```
                A         B
bar one  0.134571  0.415209
    two -1.288889 -0.144284
baz one -0.117345 -0.095292
    two -0.256708 -0.682542
```

**df_merge - current output**

```
              A_x       B_x       A_y       B_y
bar one       NaN       NaN  0.134571  0.415209
    two       NaN       NaN -1.288889 -0.144284
baz one       NaN       NaN -0.117345 -0.095292
    two       NaN       NaN -0.256708 -0.682542
foo one  2.082229  1.575985       NaN       NaN
    two -0.805592  0.444195       NaN       NaN
qux one  0.368874  0.253556       NaN       NaN
    two  1.017632 -0.471978       NaN       NaN
```

**df_merge - desired**

```
              A         B       
bar one        0.134571  0.415209
    two       -1.288889 -0.144284
baz one       -0.117345 -0.095292
    two       -0.256708 -0.682542
foo one        2.082229  1.575985       
    two       -0.805592  0.444195       
qux one        0.368874  0.253556      
    two        1.017632 -0.471978
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpliest is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), by default there is `'outer'` join and concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis (here `axis=0`, default value):

```
print (pd.concat([df_1,df_2]))

                A         B
foo one -0.329887 -0.966898
    two  0.552272 -1.964264
qux one -0.629764 -0.765578
    two -0.148118  0.904920
bar one  0.305685 -1.269400
    two  1.256213 -0.686447
baz one -2.194461  0.529666
    two -1.487217 -0.520045
```

And then [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) if necessary:

```
print (pd.concat([df_1,df_2]).sort_index())

                A         B
bar one -0.463547 -0.002780
    two -0.421346 -1.730840
baz one -0.086068  1.179000
    two  0.756876 -0.492985
foo one -0.223900 -0.302643
    two  0.460265  0.216632
qux one -0.296815  0.799978
    two -0.420700  1.147312
```

Comment: ah I just realised my minimal example wasn't great. The first hierarchy of the index should be the same for df_1 and df_2 - so there does need to be a merge as well - and concat leaves me with additional rows which requires another line of code to clean up. Is it okay for me to edit my question?

Comment: Is up to you ;)

Comment: I am a bit confused - my second solution works. Or something missing?

Comment: Ah it does work with the sort_index. Sorry, I didn't see that. Thank you!